# Ternary Operator for more than 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var testCond = $('body').hasClass('theme-a') ? 'a' : 'b';
```

Need to include new theme class name into the body like mentioned above. But, getting javascript error.

Not sure is there any easy method to solve this. Can add condition like below?

```
var testCond = $('body').hasClass('theme-a') ? 'a' : 'b' : 'c';
```

Comment: Did you mean something like check for `theme-a`, `theme-b` or `theme-c`? `var testCond = $('body').hasClass('theme-a') ? 'a' : $('body').hasClass('theme-b') ?  'b' : 'c';` should work but i'd rather go for a `switch-case` approach instead. Especially if there will be more classes in the future.

Comment: Thanks.. hope switch case may bring clear approach. not sure how to bring this in switch condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('body').hasClass('theme-a') ? 'a' : $('body').hasClass('theme-b') ? 'b' : 'c';

Answer (score 0):

A lookup table is flexible:

```
var class_lookup = { 'theme-a' : 'a', 'theme-b' : 'b', 'theme-c' : 'c', /* ... */ };
var testCondList = $('body').attr('class').split(' ').map(c => class_lookup[c]).filter(x => x);
```

This will create an array of all the values in the lookup table that has a key in the class list.